# Batch File to Copy mp3 Files With "European" Characters in the Titles

Tags: special-characters, robocopy

I have a play list of slightly more than 10,000 mp3 files. The music library has a total of about 40,000 tracks. I decided to write a batch file to copy out only the files on the playlist to a directory on a different drive. I used Notepad++ to modify the text playlist file so I would get the path/file names correct. I simply needed to add quotes around the path/file names, prefix the lines with “copy ” and suffix the lines with the destination drive/directory. Did all that, made sure the batch file was save as UTF-8 and executed it.

After a few minutes the batch file completed. When I checked the destination file I noticed that about 70 files had not copied over. I used ‘Beyond Compare’ on the original playlist file against a playlist file I made from the files that did copy over. What I noticed was that the files that did not copy over had what I will call ‘European’ characters in the filename. So like “Dov' é L'Amore.mp3” and “José Feliciano - Feliciano! - 01 -  California Dreamin'.mp3.” Other files with exclamations did not copy either.

I reran the file substituting ‘xcopy’ instead of ‘copy’ – same result. On to Robocopy - same result. At this point I decided to try and copy over one of the problem files using Robocopy at a command prompt to see what errors it reported. Surprise, surprise - it copied over, as did the others. So Robocopy at the command level will copy the files, but not in a batch file saved as UTF-8??

As a last resort I decided to try using Powershell. But as I am inexperienced in using it, I asked ChatGPT to write a script for me, and this is what it returned.

```
# Source and destination paths
$sourcePath = "F:\Directory\Music\Cher - Bob’s Cher Mix"
$destinationPath = "X:\BoboFMDrive"

# File name with special characters
$fileName = "Cher - My Cher Mix - 02 - Dov' é L'Amore.mp3"

# Full path of the source file
$sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName

# Full path of the destination file
$destinationFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $fileName

# Copy the file to the destination
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationFile -Force

Write-Host "File copied successfully!"
```

And it worked!, but I am looking for a solution that will let me easily edit a text-based file with many lines/strings as it would be onerous to have to create a script for each file.
Does anyone have any thoughts on a solution? I ended up just using ‘Beyond Compare’ and copied over the dropped files manually, but would like to find a better/easier solution for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the codepage. Windows, per default, is not using UTF-8. It uses the local ANSI codepage.
The codepage of `UTF-8` is `65001`

#### Commandline Test:

###### Prepare:

Create some filenames using different codepages:

```bash
D:\Test>  chcp
Active Codepage: 850.

D:\Test>  echo . >"Dov' é L'Amore_ansi.mp3"
D:\Test>  chcp 65001
Active Codepage: 65001

D:\Test>  echo . >"Dov' é L'Amore_utf8.mp3"
```

###### Check for Differences:

```bash
D:\Test>  chcp 850
Active Codepage: 850.

D:\Test>  dir
11.08.2023  17:08    <DIR>          .
11.08.2023  17:08    <DIR>          ..
11.08.2023  16:56                 4 Dov' é L'Amore_ansi.mp3
11.08.2023  16:58                 4 Dov' é L'Amore_utf8.mp3

D:\Test>  chcp 65001
Active Codepage: 65001

D:\Test>  dir
11.08.2023  17:08    <DIR>          .
11.08.2023  17:08    <DIR>          ..
11.08.2023  16:56                 4 Dov' é L'Amore_ansi.mp3
11.08.2023  16:58                 4 Dov' é L'Amore_utf8.mp3

D:\Test>
```

As you can see, there is no difference. Obviously Windows internally converts the used characterset before the filename it's written to the fielsystem.

###### Result:

*Therefor you have no problems, when using the commandline and batch **without any evaluation of a file content.***

#### File Test:

###### Prepare:

Using the `Notepad.exe` of Windows you can choose the file encoding during the action `Save as ...`.

Create three files with the text `Dov' é L'Amore`.
Save them encoded as

- ANSI
- UFT-8
- UTF-8 with Boom

###### Check for Differences:

```bash
D:\Test>  chcp 850
Active Codepage: 850.

D:\Test>  type ansi.txt
Dov' Ú L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8.txt
Dov' ├® L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8_boom.txt
´╗┐Dov' ├® L'Amore

D:\Test>
```

Please note the `Ú` in the `ansi.txt` content!
This is the difference between

- Local ANSI in "DOS": `850 = Latin1` and
- ANSI of Windows GUI: `1252 = Windows-1252`

As a GUI app `Notepad.exe` saved "ANSI" using characterset "Windows-1252".

```bash
D:\Test>  chcp 1252
Aktive Codepage: 1252.

D:\Test>  type ansi.txt
Dov' é L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8.txt
Dov' Ã© L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8_boom.txt
ï»¿Dov' Ã© L'Amore

D:\Test>
```

```bash
D:\Test>  chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

D:\Test>  type ansi.txt
Dov' � L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8.txt
Dov' é L'Amore

D:\Test>  type utf8_boom.txt
 Dov' é L'Amore

D:\Test>
```

(Note/compare the space before the text in `utf8_boom.txt`'s content)

*In contrast to the filesystem, **within a file the encoding in conjunction with the codepage is relevant.**

If it gets out of sync the processed filenames will differ from the ones found in the filesystem.*

---

###### Result:

- Not using UTF-8 is possible, but even when interchanging GUI and CMD-line you might come into conflicts, as the GUI-ANSI characterset might differ from the CMD-ANSI characterset.
- If you assume that there are characters present that are not part of your local ANSI, i.e. because the origin of some filenames is from a different culture, then

  - Save the playlist in UTF-8
  - Change the codepage during batch processing so the playlist file is interpreted as expected.

#### The practical part:

For scripts involving a UTF-8 text file temporarily change the codepage to UTF-8. To limit the change to the runtime of the batch, the code should be enclosed by `setlocal` / `endlocal`:

```
@echo off
setlocal
  chcp 65001

  rem   Your script ....
  type utf8.txt

endlocal
```

---

As seen here, storing the **UTF-8 with or without boom** makes no differences for the displayed characters, but the boom adds binary content. So it is better to store UTF-8 without boom, as the binary characters can irritate programs, especially when interchanging  to other operating systems.

Comment: My personal opinion about this recurring subtle problem: Microsoft should stop its regionalism in this globalized word. They should default to UTF-8 as other operating systems like Linux do since years.

Comment: Thank you so much, dodrg, for taking the time to give me such a detailed response with so many examples, etc. I have to admit that 'codepages' before your write up and it was a little over my head at first. But I read through it about 6 times and then started experimenting and soon hit on the correct syntax. Again, thanks for taking the time and teaching this old dog a new trick.

Comment: >>  I have to admit that 'codepages' << should have read "I have to admit that I knew nothing about, nor had even heard of, codepages before..."

Comment: Wikipedia has some nice summary about the origins of the [codepages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) and [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).